# Parameter not being substituted in SVN Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to automate a build process, but I am having issues with one of my script parameters.

I store the parameter and then substitute its value when I call `svn checkout %repository%` on the command line.

Problem is it doesn't substitute and I get the following output:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> .\Build_Script.bat "https://mitchellt/svn/Test_Repositry/Test_Application"

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>rem * Need to check directory exists

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>rem Variables

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>set date=13_10_2013

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>set time=16-56-48

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>set repository = https://mitchellt/svn/Test_Repositry/Test_Application

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>rem Change to build directory

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>cd C:\Build

C:\Build>rem Make Directory for Build based on today's date

C:\Build>mkdir 13_10_2013_16-56-48

C:\Build>rem Change to new directory

C:\Build>cd 13_10_2013_16-56-48

C:\Build\13_10_2013_16-56-48>rem Create folders for the source code, built product & test results

C:\Build\13_10_2013_16-56-48>mkdir Source

C:\Build\13_10_2013_16-56-48>mkdir Product

C:\Build\13_10_2013_16-56-48>mkdir Results

C:\Build\13_10_2013_16-56-48>rem Change to source directory

C:\Build\13_10_2013_16-56-48>cd Source

C:\Build\13_10_2013_16-56-48\Source>rem Copy the source code from the repository

C:\Build\13_10_2013_16-56-48\Source>svn checkout
svn: E205001: Try 'svn help checkout' for more information
svn: E205001: Not enough arguments provided
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>
```

CODE:

```
@ECHO ON
@SETLOCAL
rem * Need to check directory exists

rem Variables
set date=%DATE:/=_%
set time=%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
set repository = %1

rem Change to build directory
cd C:\Build

rem Make Directory for Build based on today's date
mkdir %date%_%time%

rem Change to new directory
cd %date%_%time%

rem Create folders for the source code, built product & test results
mkdir Source
mkdir Product
mkdir Results

rem Change to source directory
cd Source

rem Copy the source code from the repository
svn checkout %repository%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem are the spaces at `set repository = %1` and batch files are space sensitive (only sometimes at some points).
This creates a variable with the name `repository<space>`

Simply change it to

```
set repository=%1
```

Or better

```
set "repository=%~1"
```

As this also prevents problems with appended, invisble spaces after the `%1`